# How can I test Datetime for NA in Rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

using [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) I am trying to test for `NA` in a `POSIXct` vector passed to C++ (class `DatetimeVector`). It seems that the `Rcpp::is_na(.)` function works for `NumericVector`, `CharcterVector`... but not `DatetimeVector`.

Here is the `C++` code that tests `NA` for `NumericVector` and `CharacterVector` but fails to compile if you add `DatetimeVector`

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
List testNA(DataFrame df){

    const int N = df.nrows();

    //Test for NA in an IntegerVector
    IntegerVector intV = df["intV"];
    LogicalVector resInt = is_na(intV); 
    //Test for NA in an CharacterVector
    CharacterVector strV = df["strV"];
    LogicalVector resStr = is_na(strV);

    //Test for NA in an DatetimeVector
    DatetimeVector dtV = df["dtV"];
    LogicalVector resDT;
    //resDT = is_na(dtV); UNCOMMENT => DOES NOT COMPILE

    return(List::create(_["df"]=df, 
                        _["resInt"]=resInt,
                        _["resStr"]=resStr,
                        _["resDT"]=resDT));

}
/*** R
cat("testing for NA\n")
intV <- c(1,NA,2)
df <- data.frame(intV=intV, strV=as.character(intV), dtV=as.POSIXct(intV,origin='1970-01-01'))
str(df)
testNA(df)
*/
```

In R

```
library("Rcpp")
sourceCpp("theCodeAbove.cpp")
```

Comment: I might have found a way, in a loop we can do `NumericVector::is_na(dtV[i].getFractionalTimestamp());`, looks ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler error suggests the method is not (yet?) available for `DateTimeVector`s:

```
test.cpp:18:13: error: no matching function for call to 'is_na'
```

An easy workaround:

```
resDT = is_na( as<NumericVector>(dtV) ); // As per Dirk's suggestion
```

Comment: your solution is better

Comment: I'd cast to `NumericVector` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I've added (rev 4405 of Rcpp) implementations of `is_na` for `DateVector` and `DatetimeVector` that don't need the cast to `NumericVector`, which creates a temporary object we don't actually need.

However, we don't get much of a performance hit, because most of the time is taken to construct `DatetimeVector` objects.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector isna_cast( DatetimeVector d){
    // version with the cast
    return is_na( as<NumericVector>( d ) ) ;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector isna( DatetimeVector d){
    // without cast
    return is_na( d ) ;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void do_nothing( DatetimeVector d){
    // just measuring the time it takes to 
    // create a DatetimeVector from an R object    
}
```

Benchmarking this with `microbenchmark` :

```
require(microbenchmark)

intV <- rep( c(1,NA,2), 100000 )
dtV  <- as.POSIXct(intV,origin='1970-01-01')

microbenchmark( 
    isna_cast( dtV ),
    isna( dtV ), 
    do_nothing( dtV )
)

#    Unit: milliseconds
#            expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#  isna_cast(dtV) 67.03146 68.04593 68.71991 69.39960 96.46747   100
#       isna(dtV) 65.71262 66.43674 66.77992 67.16535 95.93567   100
# do_nothing(dtV) 57.15901 57.72670 58.08646 58.39948 58.97939   100
```

About 85% of the time is used to just create the `DatetimeVector` object. This is because the `DatetimeVector` and `DateVector` classes don't use the proxy design we used everywhere else in Rcpp. A `DatetimeVector` is essentially a `std::vector<Datetime>` and each of these `Datetime` objects is created from the corresponding element of the underlying object from R.

It is probably too late to change the api of `DatetimeVector` and `DateVector` and make them proxy based, but maybe there is room for something like a `POSIXct` class.

In comparison, let's measure the time it takes to do nothing with a `NumericVector`:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void do_nothing_NumericVector( NumericVector d){}

#    Unit: microseconds
#                     expr      min         lq     median        uq       max
#           isna_cast(dtV) 66985.21 68103.0060 68960.7880 69416.227 95724.385
#                isna(dtV) 65699.72 66544.9935 66893.5720 67213.064 95262.267
#          do_nothing(dtV) 57209.26 57865.1140 58306.8780 58630.236 69897.636
# do_nothing_numeric(intV)     4.22     9.6095    15.2425    15.511    33.978
```

Comment: +1 and a big "Yikes"! DatetimeVector and DateVector are in fact "survivors" from my first 0.6.* releases of Rcpp.  Seems like there is room for improvement.  New Date and POSIXct classes, maybe?  OTOH I don't really know who uses these. In practice, I mostly cast POSIXct in R via `as.numeric()` and work on the double precision values...

Comment: That's interesting. For starters we can grep around for uses of them in Rcpp client packages. If we follow design principles from the current Rcpp api, we could make them more efficient. Anyway, we'll discuss this on appropriate channels :)

Comment: Thank you Romain for adding this sugar. datetime are really fishy to work with in R, between the "display bug" of POSIXct, the relative slowness and timezones that are a mess. I regularily use `fasttime`, `RcppBDT` and still have to deal microseconds precision issues on some cases... datetimes are a piece of work.